# How to scroll QML ScrollView to center?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have code like this:

```
ScrollView {
    Image {
        source: "..."
    }
}
```

`Image` is higher than the `ScrollView`. How can I scroll the latter to the center of `Image` element?

Answer (score 14):

Despite the appearence, `ScrollView` is tightly related to `Flickable`. Indeed, `Flickable` is used to control the visible area. Such an `Item` is available as the (`readonly`) property [`flickableItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-scrollview.html#flickableItem-prop). `Flickable` has the `contentX` and `contentY` properties to control the current visible area. These properties can be combined with the `width` and `height` of the `ScrollView` to position the visible area exactly at the center. Typically you have:

```
flickableItem.contentY = flickableItem.contentHeight / 2 - height / 2
flickableItem.contentX = flickableItem.contentWidth / 2 - width / 2
```

The difference is necessary since the first calls just moves the center to the *top left point* of the visible area (where `contentX`/`contentY` are located).

Here is a complete example with an `Image` as main child of the `ScrollView`.

***Disclaimer***: *In the simple scenario proposed by the example, with a remotelly loaded image, sizes can still be unset when `onCompleted` is called, resulting in a centering code that doesn't work. By setting widths and heigths directly into code the problem is avoided. In a real scenario such detail should be unnecessary.*

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

Window {
    id: main
    visible: true
    width: 600; height: 350

    ScrollView {
        id: ss
        width: 600
        height: 350

        Image {
            id: name
            width: 900
            height: 600
            source: "http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg"
        }

        Component.onCompleted: {
            flickableItem.contentY = flickableItem.contentHeight / 2 - height / 2
            flickableItem.contentX = flickableItem.contentWidth / 2 - width / 2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with Quick Controls 2?

Comment: @VadimPeretokin take look my answer : )

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution for QQC2. Tested on Qt 5.12.

The solution is simple, just store the scrollBar pointer and control it however you want.

ScrollView2.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

ScrollView {
    id: root
    property ScrollBar hScrollBar: ScrollBar.horizontal
    property ScrollBar vScrollBar: ScrollBar.vertical

    /**
     * @param type [Qt.Horizontal, Qt.Vertical]
     * @param ratio 0.0 to 1.0
     */
    function scrollTo(type, ratio) {
        var scrollFunc = function (bar, ratio) {
            bar.setPosition(ratio - bar.size/2)
        }
        switch(type) {
        case Qt.Horizontal:
            scrollFunc(root.hScrollBar, ratio)
            break;
        case Qt.Vertical:
            scrollFunc(root.vScrollBar, ratio)
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 500
    height: 500
    ScrollView2 {
        id: scroll
        anchors.fill: parent
        Text {
            width: 1000
            height: 1000
            text: "ABC"
            font.pixelSize: 800
            Component.onCompleted: {
                scroll.scrollTo(Qt.Horizontal, 0.5)
                scroll.scrollTo(Qt.Vertical, 0.5)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since Qt 5.14 (maybe already in 5.12) you can now simply do:

```
ScrollView {
    Component.onCompleted {
        // scroll to vertical center
        ScrollBar.vertical.position = 0.5
    }

    // put your content item here:
    Image {
        // …
    }
}
```