# How to vertical scroll to a specific item

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qtquick2

I have a `ListView` including a lot of radio buttons. The list is bigger than the visible area. One of the radio buttons is checked. Sometimes, if the selected radio button is outside the visible area I want to scroll to it:

```
ScrollView {
    anchors.fill:parent
    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: valuesList
        delegate: RadioButton {
            id: radioBtn
            //check of value is index type and do the corresponding checked? test
            checked: valueIsIndex ? (parseInt(valueFromParent) == index ? true : false) : (valueFromParent == valueString ? true : false)
            onClicked: {
                 root.selected(valueString, index)
            }    
            Component.onCompleted: {
                 if(checked) 
                //Here i want to scroll the list to display this radiobutton
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas howto to get the list scrolled? I've played around a lot of with `hightlights` and `contentY` but nothing worked.

I've use the `ScrollView` around the `ListView` to automatically get the systems scrollbars on the desktop. On mobile devices i have just the flickable `ListView`.

**EDIT**

I get it on the way with the help of BaCaRoZzo. Here is my current working example:

```
ScrollView {
    id: scrollView
    anchors.fill:parent
    property int yOfCheckedRadioButton: 0
    ListView {
        id:listView
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: Math.round(appWindow.height*0.05)
        model: internalValuesList
        delegate: RadioButton {
            id: radioBtn
            //check of value is index type and do the corresponding checked? test
            checked: checktest()
            style: MyRadioButtonStyle {
                myRadioBtn: radioBtn
                labelString: value
            }
            Component.onCompleted: {
                //set the position of the checked RadioButton to scroll to it later onContentHeightChange
                if(checked) {
                    var checkedRadioBtnPositionY = Math.round((radioBtn.height + listView.spacing) * index - radioBtn.height * 1.5)
                    if( checkedRadioBtnPositionY > 0)
                        scrollView.yOfCheckedRadioButton = checkedRadioBtnPositionY
                    else
                        scrollView.yOfCheckedRadioButton = 0
                }
            }
        }
        onContentHeightChanged: {
            //scroll to the checked RadioButton
            contentY = scrollView.yOfCheckedRadioButton
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ContentY` should work (as for instance shown by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30378458/2538363)). You should surely take in account the presence of the `ListView` here.

Comment: As a basic test i tried following at the end of `ListView`:
    `Component.onCompleted: {
        contentY = 200
    }`
But this also does not change anything. What I'am doing wrong?

Comment: Nope like that. [This](http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=EwT9nfRH) works

Comment: Thank you. I realized that it depends on my model. When i use a static one like in your example it works like a charm. But when i dynamically create it after the `Component` is completed the scroll action is useless. So i need to scroll depending on: `onContentHeightChanged`.
Now i just have to figure out how to calculate the position of the checked radio button ...

Comment: No problem. You can try to reduce your code to a minimum working example and edit the question. It could be worth a try. :)

Comment: I will do, but currently i get stuck with the calculation of the checked `RadioButton` position in the `ListView`. Do you have a hint for me? `y` of the `RadioButton` is 0. Is there something like getYInParent(myListView, radioBtn)? I can not find in the docs ...

Comment: You can use [`mapfromItem()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#mapFromItem-method-2) function. Have a look also to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27078608/2538363) for details about `ListView`. In this case `ScrollView` supersedes `ListView` so that details about the linked answer do NOT apply but it is worth a read.

Comment: I found a way and edited the question with my current working example. Unfortunately it is not the way with mapfromItem() because i don't get the point WHEN i should try to map it. When doing it in `Component.onCompleted` in the `RadioButton` delegate with `mapfromItem(listview, radioBtn.x, radioBtn.y).y` i get always 0. Maybe it is the problem that when the radioBtn is completed it is not added into the listView. But when i try to add `mapfromItem()` into the `onContentHeightChanged:` part in `listView` i dont know howto access the checked item to get its x and y for the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

I recall problems with scroll before Qt 5.4 when I found a workaround like:

```
        ScrollView {
            anchors.fill: parent // mind how you stretch it
            contentItem:
                Flow {
                    id: flow
                    spacing: 10 // mind gaps
                    width: parent.parent.width - 20 // select proper width

                    // Put anything you would like to scroll in here
                    // Mind that Flow positions items one after another
                    // left to right, top to bottom

                    // You can also try containers other than Flow
                    // but whether it works or not may depend on Qt version

                    ExclusiveGroup { id: tabPositionGroup }
                    RadioButton {
                        text: "RB1"
                        checked: true
                        exclusiveGroup: tabPositionGroup
                    }
                    RadioButton {
                        text: "RB2"
                        exclusiveGroup: tabPositionGroup
                    }
                }
        }
```

Whether ScrollView needs an explicit contentItem or not is another matter and it certainly may not need it but that does not hurt if the SrollView needs to resolve what it actually scrolls.

Comment: It seems to do not work when i try to wrap the `ScrollView` around the `ListView`. I tried to place the `ListView` into the `Flow` but then, it just shows ONE radio button.

Comment: What if you add some radio buttons like in fixed example? Immediately to the Flow? I used such pattern for different type of content including dynamic.

Comment: And I guess that I missed width for the Flow. Also fixed.

Comment: Do you think about a `Repeater` for dynamically created radio buttons?

Comment: Yes, we can use Repeater though it is a bit inconvenient. First create some number of items and then go via them using itemAt(index) and set their individual properties.