# Get scroll position of ScrollArea

Tags: qt, scroll, qml, qtquick2

How do I get the scroll position of a QtQuick2 `ScrollView`? I tried `scrollView.contentItem.y` and `scrollView.viewport.y` but both return 0 always.

I think one solution might be to put a `Flickable` as the `ScrollView`'s child. Is that gonna solve the problem? Also to me that's a hack, any way that's not a hack?

Comment: You really only need the flickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, the `contentItem.x/y` are always 0. 
However you can retrive the values you are looking for from either the parent of the `contentItem` (which is not the `ScrollView` but the `contentItem` of a `Flickable`, the `flickableItem`) with `contentItem.parent.x/y`or from the `flickableItem` with `flickableItem.contentX/Y`. The relation between both is: `flickableItem.contentX === -flickableItem.contentItem.x`

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 400; height: 450

    ScrollView {
        id: sv
        anchors.fill: parent
        contentItem: Rectangle {
            id: rect
            width: 800
            height: 800
            gradient: Gradient {
                GradientStop { position: 0; color: 'grey' }
                GradientStop { position: 1; color: 'red' }
            }
        }
    }

    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: sv.contentItem.parent.x + ' / ' + sv.contentItem.parent.y + '\n'
              + sv.flickableItem.contentX  + ' / ' + sv.flickableItem.contentY + '\n'
              + sv.flickableItem.contentItem.x  + ' / ' + sv.flickableItem.contentItem.y + '\n'
              + sv.flickableItem.contentItem + '\t' + sv.contentItem.parent // Just to suport my claim, both are the same
        color: 'white'
    }
}
```

As *dtech* already pointed out:
It might be better, to use the `Flickable` directly. If needed, you can attatch [`ScrollBar`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollbar.html)s from the new `QtQuick.Controls 2.x` to it.

I have no measurements, but the QTees were boasting about, that the new `QtQuick.Controls 2.x` are supperior performancewise. By the way, they are easier to use and to style, but don't support the native look and feel. Here you would have the properties `contentX/Y`

Comment: You should refer to `flickableItem`, see e.g. my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30378458/2538363).